# How to calculate TF-IDF (using tft.tfidf function) in Tensorflow Transform

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, nlp, tensorflow2.0, tf-idf

While going through the docs in tensorflow transform I came across function to perform TD-IDF.

```
tft.tfidf(
    x, vocab_size, smooth=True, name=None
)
```

As the docs in not clear in providing example of how to perform TD-IDF I tried using example_string

```
example_strings=[["I", "like", "pie", "pie", "pie"], ["yum", "yum", "pie"]]
```

and a vocab size of 1000.(Just random number) but the below code giving me an attribute error.

```
tft.tfidf(example_strings, vocab_size=1000)
```

**AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'indices'**

Please help me to figure this out as I am naive to Tensorflow transform ops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you would like to compute the tfidf with TFT ([here an example](https://github.com/tensorflow/transform/blob/7f8bc85d5f3a055b1f711b75168bbf970c678839/examples/sentiment_example.py#L187-L192)) you can do

```
example_strings = ["I like pie pie pie", "yum yum pie"]
VOCAB_SIZE = 100

tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

tokens = tf.compat.v1.string_split(example_strings)
indices = tft.compute_and_apply_vocabulary(tokens, top_k=VOCAB_SIZE)
bow_indices, weight = tft.tfidf(indices, VOCAB_SIZE + 1)
```

otherwise, you can also use TF [Tokenizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/text/Tokenizer):

```
tk = tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer(num_words=VOCAB_SIZE)
tk.fit_on_texts(example_strings)

tk.sequences_to_matrix(tk.texts_to_sequences(example_strings), mode='tfidf')
```